# how to seperate date and time in mssql table in to two columns

Tags: sql-server, database, mssql-jdbc

i have view having a date column that includes both date and time ,i want seperate that columns in to date and time columns

I tried the getdate function its not working , here is my example sql table data

```
title  description       date
sample  this is sample   2018-11-08 23:59:59.000
```

i want to have

```
date           time 
2018-11-08    23:59
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
select cast(date as date), left(cast(date as time), 5)
```

You can easily do conversation with simple `SELECT` statement.

If you want separate `date` & `time`, then use `ALTER` statement to modify :

```
alter table t
     add [date] as CAST( [date] as date),
     add [time] as CAST( [date] as time(0))
```

Comment: i am getting error type date is not define system type and type time is not defined system type

Comment: @vyshnavi. . So, you are using lower version of `SQL Server` ??

Comment: mine is  mssql 9.0.5057 version

Comment: @vyshnavi that version doesn't support `date` it's introduced in SQL Server 2008 (version 10), also the database itself is not supported anymore. You should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably might need to use the date and time together, I'd suggest to create 2 computed columns. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData(
    title       varchar(15),
    description varchar(100),
    [date]      datetime
)
INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES( 'sample', 'this is sample', '2018-11-08 23:59:59.000')

ALTER TABLE SampleData
    ADD dateonly AS CAST( [date] as date),
        timeonly AS CAST( [date] as time)

SELECT * FROM SampleData;
```